# How to filter time-related images in Google Earth Engine and conduct regression analysis to verify the consistency of different sensors？

Tags: google-earth-engine

Landsat data harmony is shown on the Google developer website(https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/landsat-etm-to-oli-harmonization), but I want to verify this harmony result by selecting sample points to merge. What should I do?
Below is a link to the original code(https://code.earthengine.google.com/798ae7a268f8e2c8022433b9562785c0)

Comment: Do you have a workflow sketched out? I suggest start with a "brute force" approach; first pick some pair of images you want to compare, then reduce a band within some sample region to an `ee.Array` and print a [scatterplot](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_array_values) to the screen with and without the gains/offsets from the Roy et al. paper

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. I think it is more feasible.